# SIM900 GSM Module | How to check if the outgoing-call is answered

Tags: serial-port, gsm, at-command, sim900, outgoing-call

After sending an **outgoing call** using SIM900 GSM module using **AT commands**, is there a way to know if the person receiving the **call has answered** it?

**(directly communicating with GSM module using serial)**

Answer (score 3):

The command `+CLCC` is the ***standard way*** to perform what you are asking. It means that this command will be available in any device supporting ETSI specification whatever is the model or the vendor.

From SIM900 [AT command guide](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.11.pdf):

> Execution command **`AT+CLCC`** returns a list of current calls of ME.
> **Note:** if Command succeeds but no calls are available, no information response is sent to TE.
>
> The following response is sent by the device
>
> `[+CLCC: <id1>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type >,<alphaID>]`
> `[<CR><LF>+CLCC: <id2>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type>,<alphaID>]`
> `[...]]]`
> `OK`
>
> **where**
>
> **<idx>** - (Range 1..7) - Call  identification  number
> This number can be used in `+CHLD` command operations
> **<dir>**
> 0 - Mobile originated (MO) call
> 1 - Mobile terminated (MT) call
> **<stat>** - State of the call:
> 0 - Active
> 1 - Held
> 2 - Dialing (MO call)
> 3 - Alerting (MO call)
> 4 - Incoming (MT call)
> 5 - Waiting (MT call)
> 6 - Disconnect
> **<mode>** - Bearer/tele service:
> 0 - Voice
> 1 - Data
> 2 - Fax
> **<mpty>**
> 0 - Call is not one of multiparty (conference) call parties
> 1 - Call is one of multiparty (conference) call parties
> **<number>** - String type (string should be included in quotation marks) phone number in format specified by <type>.
> **<type>** - Type of address
> **<alphaId>** - String type (string should be included in quotation marks) alphanumeric representation of <number> corresponding to the entry found in phone book.

So, basically, what you need to do is to provide the command (in polling), search for the row of the answer containing the remote number you are dialing to, contained in **<number>** parameter, and wait until the value of parameter **<stat>** changes from `2` (Dialing) to `0` (Active).

---

An alternative way for obtaining the info, not involving polling, is to enable **URC**s (unsolicited result codes). By setting

```
AT+CLCC=1
```

an URC will be *asynchronously* sent to the serial port whenever the call status changes (with the same format of the execution command respose explained above).

---

### An easier SIM900 specific solution

It involves `AT+MORING` command. From AT command guide:

> **`AT+MORING=<mode>`**
> Show State of Mobile Originated Call.
>
> **<mode>**
> 0 - Not show call state of mobile originated call
> 1 - Show call state of mobile originated call. After the call number is dialed, the URC strings of MO RING will be sent if another call is alerted and the URC strings of **MO CONNECTED** will be sent if the call is established.

So, providing

```
AT+MORING=1
```

will enable a family of URCs in case of Mobile Originated call, in the form

> **MO RING** - the call is alerted.
> **MO  CONNECTED** - the call is established

Comment: Thanks Roberto, I will try and let you know